# How to specify the image version if image is built using "build" attribute

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

How to specify the image version if the Dockerfile is available as part of folder foo and we use the build option to build it in docker-compose.yaml file. It says "latest" otherwise, but we want to specify something like 0.0.1

```
  foo-gateway:
    container_name: "foo-gateway"
    build: foo
    ports:
      - 9000:80
      - 9090:8080

foo/dockerfile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide the image name:

```yaml
  foo-gateway:
    container_name: "foo-gateway"
    image: foo:0.0.1
    build: foo
    ports:
      - 9000:80
      - 9090:8080
```